# Developer Edition with no Developer Settings?

Tags: managed-package

I'm most likely going to need to open a case with Salesforce, but I figured I'd ask here, too, to see if anyone else has had this problem.

I created a Developer Edition org from our Environment Hub and have logged in.  I'm ready to configure Developer Settings so I can create a namespace and start building out a managed package.  According to the docs:

```
To configure your developer settings:

1. From Setup, enter Packages in the Quick Find box, then select Packages.

...
```

There is no "Packages" in the Dev Edition org that I'm currently working in.  I've double-checked everything that I could to ensure that I'm doing this right (which doesn't mean anything, really, but I'm fairly sure I haven't done anything incorrectly).  I tried to create a second Dev Edition org to test my sanity but it doesn't have Packages in Setup either.  The permissions are all there to create packages, just not the option for Packages.

Has anyone else experienced this?  Again, I'll most likely open a ticket but if someone else has any insight I'm always appreciative.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering my own question, I'm putting this out there in case anyone else runs in the same circle that I did.

So, both developer documentation and KB state that (ref: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=configure_developer_settings.htm&type=5 and https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.packagingGuide.meta/packagingGuide/configure_developer_settings.htm)

```
To configure your developer settings:
1. From Setup, enter Packages in the Quick Find box, then select Packages.
...
```

If you search for Packages all you get back is the typical
[image: Search for Package]

No "Packages".  I ended up opening a ticket only to have the support tech tell me that they were able to get to the Developer Settings in my DE.  After some back and forth I realized what was going on.

Everything I needed was in Package Manager.  The top section of Package Manager is labelled Packages.  And, lo and behold, directly underneath that is the section Developer Settings with the Edit button to take you where you can create the namespace, etc.  I'm not sure why I didn't see this before, but honestly what I was looking for was a Setup area named Packages, not Package Manager/Packages.  The documentation leads you to believe that there is a section in Setup named Packages, and also tells you to look specifically for that... which won't return anything.

[image]

I'll take the blame for part of this for not being more aware, but I really was looking for something else so I wasn't paying attention to what was already there.  I'll take half the blame... well, maybe 35%.

Anyway, hope this helps someone else out.  Thanks for playing!

Comment: Developer Settings seems to have dissappeard from there now. And this page https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pkg2_dev.meta/pkg2_dev/sfdx_dev_dev2gp_before.htm tells you to set up Dev Hub then the Package Manager tells you that you can't do the next steps unless you're not using Dev Hub.